# React big Calendar error Uncaught TypeError: d[("get" + method)] is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, calendar, react-big-calendar

i have this error, i've been looking and this may occur because RBC only acepts Date objets but still cant solve it im kind of new with React.

problem explained: i set a new date, then i add it to localStorage, i get that date from the localStorage so i can show it on the calendar, but when i switch to week or day view it crashes and shows me that error.

Code component:

```
const Calendario = ({ nombre, turno }) => {
  const [allEvents, setAllEvents] = useState([]);

  const handleSelectSlot = useCallback(
    ({ start, end }) => {
      const id = uuidv4();
      const title = window.prompt("Turno:");
      if (title) {
        setAllEvents((prev) => [...prev,{ start: new Date(Date.parse(start)),
          end: new Date(Date.parse(end)), title, id }]);
      }
    },
    [allEvents]
  );
  const locales = {
    "es-US": require("date-fns/locale/en-US"),
  };

  const localizer = dateFnsLocalizer({
    format,
    parse,
    startOfWeek,
    getDay,
    locales,
  });

  const saveData = () => {
    localStorage.setItem(`${turno}`, JSON.stringify(allEvents));
    console.log("guardado");
  };
  const obtenerDatos = () => {
   const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`${turno}`));
    if (items) {
      setAllEvents(items);
    } 
  }
  

  useEffect(() => {
    obtenerDatos(allEvents)
  }, []);

  console.log(allEvents);
return (
<div>
      <div className="calendar-subContainer">
        <h2>{nombre}</h2>
        <div onClick={() => saveData()} className="guardado">
          <p className="save-text"> Guardar turno</p>
        </div>
      </div>
<Calendar
        localizer={localizer}
        events={allEvents}
        startAccessor="start"
        endAccessor="end"
        onSelectSlot={handleSelectSlot}
        selectable
        popup={true}
        style={{ height: 900, width: 1400, margin: "50px" }}
      />
</div>
```

i've tried to set end and start to Date objects, but still nothing o maybe im doing it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, `JSON.parse()` will turn your original date object into a string. Here's a quick proof:

[image]

A possible solution to make it works is to convert back each start and end date into a Date object. The downside is it requires a `.map()` (which can be expensive if you have a lot of event data).

Here's how to get it done:

```js
  const obtenerDatos = () => {
   const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`${turno}`));
    if (items) {
      const events = items.map(item => ({
       ...item,
       start: new Date(item.start),
       end: new Date(item.end)
      }))
      setAllEvents(events);
    } 
  }
```

Hope it helps!